# Google Analytics Event Tracking - Form with checkboxes

Tags: forms, events, google-analytics, tracking

Is it possible to track several checkboxes with event tracking?

For example:

```
Name:
email:

checkbox 1  x
checkbox 2  x
checkbox 3
checkbox 4  x
```

Now I would like to track that checkboxes 1,2 and 4 were enabled, but only if the form has been filled out successful. If the user forgot the fill out name or mail, no event should be tracked.